# Java execution not working with -classpath

Tags: java

Test.java

```
package test;

 import shape.twod.*;
 import shape.threed.*;
 import shape.*;

public class Test {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of <code>Test</code>.
     */
     int o;
    public Test() {

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ObjActions obj[] = new ObjActions[4];
        obj[0] = new Line(1,2,3,4);
        obj[1] = new Circle(1,2,3);
        obj[2] = new Line3D(1,2,3,4,5,6);
        obj[3] = new Sphere(1,2,3,4);
        for(ObjActions x: obj)
            x.draw();
        ObjActions.Actions2D o =(Circle)obj[1];
        //Actions2D o =(Circle)obj[1];
        System.out.println("Area of circle "+o.area());
        ObjActions.Actions3D op = (Sphere)obj[3];
        System.out.println("Volume of sphere "+op.volume());
    }
}
```

Its location is `D:\Program\Javalearningprograms` and the location of packages used is `D:\Program\Javalearningprograms\PackageCheck`

First I compiled it with

`javac -classpath .\PackageCheck -d .\ Test.java`

It compiled successfully and created Test.class in `.\test`, then I used this

`java -classpath .\PackageCheck test.Test`

and got `Error: Could not find or load main class test.Test`

so I tried with the full path:

`java -classpath D:\Program\Javalearningprograms\PackageCheck\ test.Test`

and

`java -classpath D:\Program\Javalearningprograms\PackageCheck test.Test`

still got `Error: Could not find or load main class test.Test`

So then to check weather the .class file has any errors I moved folder `.\test` to `D:\Program\Javalearningprograms\PackageCheck` and tried

`java test.Test` from `D:\Program\Javalearningprograms\PackageCheck` and the program ran successfully

then I set `CLASSPATH` environment variable to `D:\Program\Javalearningprograms\PackageCheck` and cleaned the .class files and then tried

`javac -classpath .\PackageCheck -d .\ Test.java` it created Test.class in `.\test` folder and the I used

`java test.Test` and the program ran successfully, I tried

`java -classpath .\PackageCheck test.Test`

`java -classpath .\PackageCheck\ test.Test`

`java -classpath D:\Program\Javalearningprograms\PackageCheck test.Test`

`java -classpath D:\Program\Javalearningprograms\PackageCheck\ test.Test`

and got `Error: Could not find or load main class test.Test`

I dont know why `-classpath` is not working with `java` command, what am I doing wrongly?

```
    Directory: D:\Program\Javalearningprograms\PackageCheck


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        09-Dec-15   1:35 PM                baseobj
d-----        09-Dec-15   1:35 PM                shape
-a----        09-Dec-15   1:33 PM            559 Circle.java
-a----        09-Dec-15   1:33 PM            566 Line.java
-a----        09-Dec-15   1:33 PM            627 Line3D.java
-a----        09-Dec-15   1:32 PM            384 ObjActions.java
-a----        08-Dec-15   9:58 PM            340 Point.java
-a----        08-Dec-15   9:58 PM            302 Point3D.java
-a----        08-Dec-15  10:05 PM            343 PointTest.java
-a----        09-Dec-15   1:33 PM            547 Sphere.java
```

Comment: Can we see what you have in "D:\Program\Javalearningprograms\PackageCheck\" (a `dir /s`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html:

> The default class path is the **current** directory. [...] Using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "."

That should explain what you observed - by default, your class is at `test/Test.class` but as soon as you add the `-classpath` option you need to include the current directory, like

```
java -classpath .\PackageCheck;. test.Test
```

My moving the `test/Test.class` file below the `PackageCheck` directory, `java` was again able to find it even without the current directory being part of the classpath. Remember that the `-classpath` option defines the root paths where to look for the fully qualified java classes - with the detail that the current directory is not automatically included anymore once you use `-classpath`.

Comment: What JVM/JDK (vendor and version) on which Operating system are you using? From the paths you showed, I was assuming Windows ... If unsure about java, use `java -version`

Comment: `java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode)`

Comment: I was using Powershell and then I tried `java -classpath .\PackageCheck;. test.Test` in cmd and it worked

Comment: Then why `javac -classpath .\PackageCheck -d .\ Test.java` worked? I am overriding the default with `-classpath` but still it worked.

Comment: **javac** does not need to lookup your `Test` class - actually it **can** not since it is the one which is just getting compiled. `javac` requires the `-classpath` argument to resolve any **other** classes which the one which is just getting compiled depends on.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `Test.class` is not in a directory of your classpath.

```
javac -classpath .\PackageCheck -d .\ Test.java
```

Creates the file `test\Test.class`.

But with your defined classpath `-classpath .\PackageCheck` it cannot be found in directory `test\`.

Change your command to

```
java -classpath .\PackageCheck;. test.Test
```

This will find classes below `PackageCheck\` and the current directory.

**edit** Based on the amended question, it seems `PackageCheck\` contains only source files. So all generated class files will be stored below the current directory as

```
shape\twod\*.class
shape\threed\*.class
shape\*.class
test\*.class
```

Either you run your code with `java -cp . test.Test` or store the compiled classes into a dedicated directory (must be created before) `javac -cp .\PackageCheck -d bin Test.java`. Then you can run your code with `java -cp bin test.Test`. (Keep in mind to remove already created class files to be sure they are not taken from a wrong directory.)

Comment: @Sab See my upated answer.

Comment: I have done `javac -d .\ *.java` from `PackageCheck`

Comment: I was using Powershell and then I tried `java -classpath .\PackageCheck;. test.Test` in cmd and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
javac -d PackageCheck Test.java
```

and after compiling

```
java -cp PackageCheck test.Test
```